# .htaccess. Redirect requests to ~username folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Situation:

I'm moving a website from a production environment to a test environment.

The test environment url is similar to   `http://192.168.1.100/~username/`

There are thousands of files which use the following within the html

```
<img src='/images/image.jpg' />
```

Since the request is going to root `http://192.168.1.100/` the files are 404.

Rather than finding and replacing all of html I'd assume that there is an easy way to fix it with mod_rewrite via .htaccess.

I've tried using the following

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/~username/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~username/$1
```

But did not work as expected.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
The development environment resides within cpanel/whm.  So when the username is removed from the requested url, it now belongs to the root users.  So, my question now:  How do I update the .htaccess file for the root user to mod_rewrite back to the ~username?

Comment: How is it not working as expected? The rules look fine, in a blank htaccess file, they work fine.

Comment: Perhaps because ~username is a vhost, and when the file is requested as http://192.168.1.100/, it is looking under the root user.    Maybe I just answered my own question

Answer (score 0):

If you remove

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

it appears to work as expected, because any request to the right url will not be rewritten.

you might want to add `[L]` as a flag to signify it's the last rewrite rule, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/~username/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~username/$1 [L]
```